# Why Would My Camera Intent Kill The App Only After Opening a Webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-camera

So I'm experiencing what seems fairly odd to me. I have an activity in my application that allows users to take a photo and then send it, and it works perfectly fine on its own. However, if I go to another part of the application and start a Web View, and then go back to the camera, the application is killed as soon as I take a picture. Does anyone have a guess or know why that is? I'm confused as to how the webview could do such a thing. It works every time, without fail, until I load the webview activity.

```
void SelectImage() {
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent
                (Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception:", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void TakePhoto() {
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception:", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    try {
        Log.d("Result Code:", Integer.toString(resultCode));
        if(data != null)
            Log.d("Data Results:", data.getDataString());

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            if (requestCode == 0 || requestCode == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Photo Submission From Android");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"a@b.com"});
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Your Photo!"), 2);
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) { Log.d("Exception:", e.toString()); e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

And The Webview activity:;

```
public class Activity_WebView extends FragmentActivity {
    static WebView m_WebView;
    ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog;
    boolean m_FirstLoad = true;
    String m_RequestType = null;

    String m_OrderUrl = "";

String m_FacebookUrl = "https://mobile.facebook.com/";
String m_TwitterUrl = "https://mobile.twitter.com/";

private class LocalWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        try {
            if (m_FirstLoad) {
                m_ProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity_WebView.this);
                m_ProgressDialog.setTitle("Gathering Data..");
                m_ProgressDialog.setMessage("One Moment Please");
                m_ProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                m_ProgressDialog.show();
                m_FirstLoad = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Error:", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        try {
            if (m_ProgressDialog.isShowing())
                m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Error:", e.toString());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.removeAllViews();
    super.finish();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        String tempUrl = "";
        m_RequestType = getIntent().getStringExtra("requestType");
        switch (m_RequestType)
        {
            case "menu": {
                tempUrl = m_OrderUrl;
                break;
            }

            case "facebook": {
                tempUrl = m_FacebookUrl;
                break;
            }

            case "twitter": {
                tempUrl = m_TwitterUrl;
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        m_WebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        m_WebView.setWebViewClient(new LocalWebViewClient());

        m_WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        m_WebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        m_WebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        m_WebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        m_WebView.loadUrl(tempUrl);

        m_FirstLoad = true;
    }

    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); Log.d("Error:", e.toString()); }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you have a look at the logcat?? If any error please mention it

Comment: I just added the intent code to the post, but unfortunately there's no error being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about memory. Web View consumes quite a lot, and Camera app needs quite a lot. You can try this on emulator, playing with the size of RAM.

Actually, camera intent is not special: try to start rating intent - the pattern will be very similar.

Comment: It finally spit out a java.nio.BufferOverflowException, is there a means of clearing the buffer I can invoke before taking each picture?

Comment: If you close the web page (navigate to **about:blank**) before going for camera, your chances are much higher

Comment: Unfortunately it still crashes once I get to picture five or six.